# How does QnAMaker Update API know which one to update?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

The QnAMaker [KB Update API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamaker/knowledgebase/update#updateqnadto) has the following payload:

```
  "update": {
"name": "QnA Maker FAQ Prompts Bot",
"qnaList": [
  {
    "id": 2,
    "answer": "You can use our REST apis to create a KB. See here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cognitiveservices/qnamaker/knowledgebase/create",
    "source": "Custom Editorial",
    "questions": {
      "add": [],
      "delete": []
    },
    "metadata": {
      "add": [],
      "delete": []
    },
    "context": {
      "isContextOnly": false,
      "promptsToAdd": [
        {
          "displayText": "Add Prompts",
          "displayOrder": 0,
          "qna": {
            "id": 0,
            "answer": "Click here to know more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation",
            "source": "Editorial",
            "questions": [
              "How can I add prompts?"
            ],
            "metadata": [],
            "alternateQuestionClusters": [],
            "context": {
              "isContextOnly": false,
              "prompts": []
            }
          },
          "qnaId": 0
        },
        {
          "displayText": "Delete Prompts",
          "displayOrder": 0,
          "qna": {
            "id": 0,
            "answer": "Click here to know more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/multiturn-conversation",
            "source": "Editorial",
            "questions": [
              "How can I delete delete prompts?"
            ],
            "metadata": [],
            "alternateQuestionClusters": [],
            "context": {
              "isContextOnly": false,
              "prompts": []
            }
          },
          "qnaId": 0
        },
        {
          "displayText": "Update Knowledgebase",
          "displayOrder": 0,
          "qna": null,
          "qnaId": 3
        }
      ],
      "promptsToDelete": [
        3
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

}
}

How do I know what is the 'id' of the Question that i want to update. My requirement is to update the text (string) of an answer programatically. The existing set of questions and answers were loaded initially by someone else and  I am unable to see the unique id for every question & answer pair in the UI anywhere. How do I target a particular question & answer set for update?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API to get these pair of ID / Questions, especially `Get Download Knowledgebase` operation.

The operation details are listed [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download).

You can directly test in the console using your Knowledge Base ID and your key: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5a93fcf85b4ccd136866eb37/operations/knowledgebases_download/console

The result will have the following format:

```
{
  "qnaDocuments": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "answer": "You can change the default message if you use the QnAMakerDialog. See this for details: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/azure-bot-service/templates/qnamaker/#navtitle",
      "source": "Custom Editorial",
      "questions": [
        "How can I change the default message from QnA Maker?"
      ],
      "metadata": []
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "answer": "You can use our REST apis to manage your KB. See here for details: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/58994a073d9e04097c7ba6fe/operations/58994a073d9e041ad42d9baa",
      "source": "Custom Editorial",
      "questions": [
        "How do I programmatically update my KB?"
      ],
      "metadata": [
        {
          "name": "category",
          "value": "api"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "answer": "QnA Maker provides an FAQ data source that you can query from your bot or application. Although developers will find this useful, content owners will especially benefit from this tool. QnA Maker is a completely no-code way of managing the content that powers your bot or application.",
      "source": "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/faqs",
      "questions": [
        "Who is the target audience for the QnA Maker tool?"
      ],
      "metadata": []
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "answer": "<p>You can sign in with your <a href=\"https://account.microsoft.com/account\" data-linktype=\"external\">Microsoft account</a></p>",
      "source": "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/faqs",
      "questions": [
        "How do I sign in to the QnA Maker portal?"
      ],
      "metadata": []
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "answer": "<p>Yes, currently the QnA Maker tool is free to use. However, usage is metered for each account. For more information, see <a href=\"https://qnamaker.ai/Documentation/Authentication\" data-linktype=\"external\">Authentication and subscription keys</a></p>",
      "source": "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/faqs",
      "questions": [
        "Is the QnA Maker Service free?"
      ],
      "metadata": []
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nicholas R, thanks for your response. So the logic to update an answer of Q&A pair would be (a) Get all Q&A pairs from remote (b) Iterate through them and find the one that you need to update through some kinda string match (c) get the id and then use update api to update the data; correct?  Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you are right. The best way is maybe to store these associations id <> questions into a database on your side to avoid this mechanism each time you want to update

Comment: Thanks @nicolas. Yes we are planning to do something similar. Create a UUID that becomes the association between us and QNA and then use that as the id attribute when storing data, so there is some connection, or we may use meta tags for further filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than Downloading the Knowledgebase and having to try to find the the proper question, I would suggest letting QnA Maker do the work via the [Generate Answer endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage). The request URL is `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/metadata-generateanswer-usage` and you'll also need your key in the header. But if you can make that call, you'll get an answer back like:

```
{
    "answers": [
        {
            "score": 38.54820341616869,
            "Id": 20,
            "answer": "There is no direct integration of LUIS with QnA Maker. But, in your bot code, you can use LUIS and QnA Maker together. [View a sample bot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/Node/samples/QnAMaker/QnAWithLUIS)",
            "source": "Custom Editorial",
            "questions": [
                "How can I integrate LUIS with QnA Maker?"
            ],
            "metadata": [
                {
                    "name": "category",
                    "value": "api"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It sounds like you might not be sure of the question text, so if you do it this way, you can also use the returned `score` value to check if the confidence is high enough to make an update. Once you have that Id you can call the programmatic API as you described in your question.

Comment: Thanks @billoverton, we are planning to use a combination of id & meta tags to better filter for updates. Reading all and looping to find is a bit expensive.

Comment: That’s another workaround but I prefer getting all the KB to ensure that I’m pointing to the right thing, rather than using the query engine and having a mismatch risk.